# Need to convert date format in apex

Tags: apex

i want to convert

> 2015-07-27 00:00:00

into

> mm/dd/yyyy

format in salesforce(Apex).

i have search the net do not get any proper way.pls help.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try extracting the date part in a String variable and then create a new instance of Date with your format.

```
String ExtractedDate = '2015-07-27';

list<String> lstSplitDate = ExtractedDate.split('-');
Date myDate = date.newinstance(Integer.valueOf(lstSplitDate[0]), Integer.valueOf(lstSplitDate[1]), Integer.valueOf(lstSplitDate[2]));
```

Home this will help you ;)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like SQL date format from ISO 9075:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Apex [Datetime.valueOfGmt(string)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_valueOfGmt) can inhale it:

```
Datetime midnight = Datetime.valueOfGmt('2015-07-27 00:00:00');
```

Then you can use [Datetime.formatGmt(format)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_formatGmt) to output it:

```
midnight.formatGmt('MM/dd/yy'); //gives you "07/27/15"
```

Be careful with the GMT input and output to avoid moving off the exact date boundary. Manual formatting should be used sparingly; instead the running user's locale setting should be respected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DateTime.format method - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_2